# Valores "basura" en arrays?

Tags: c

eh estado practicando como utilizar vectores en c, y me eh topado en varios programas sencillos que eh hecho con valores "basura", por ejemplo en el siguiente código que consiste en que el usuario teclee su nombre completo, incluyendo espacios:

```
int main()
{
 int nombre,i=0;
 char s[20];
  printf("introdusca su nombre\n");
  while ((nombre = getchar()) != '\n')
   {
      s[i] = nombre;
      i++;
   }
  printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

al ejecutar el programa, si se logra imprimir el nombre incluyendo los espacios, pero el problema es que se añaden muchos signos como estos ╗┐ seguidos del nombre impreso, no se cual es el problema, al igual que cuando uso arrays pero en lugar de caracteres son números, me sucede algo parecido, pero en lugar de ╗┐, me salen números extremadamente grandes en lugar de los que tecleo.

Comment: estas compilando dentro de visual studio y por eso el tag?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: gracias, no había leído esa guía, me servirá de mucho, y si, estoy compilando en visual studio.

Comment: puede utlizar la funcion memset para inicializar el array http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/

Answer (score 5):

En C las cadenas de caracteres se almacenan con **terminación por carácter nulo**. Esto significa que al final de una cadena de caracteres se coloca una caracter nulo `'\0'`. Este caracter hace de marcador que permite saber a las funciones de tratamiento de cadenas que se ha llegado al final de la cadena. `printf` es una de esas funciones.

Con el código que has escrito se almacenan los caracteres que pulsa el usuario hasta que pulse salto de línea. Pero nunca se almacena el terminador de caracter nulo. Por eso el `printf` imprime lo que ha escrito el usuario seguido de la basura que hubiese en el array.

La solución es guardar el caracter nulo a continuación del último caracter guardado:

```
int main()
{
 int nombre,i=0;
 char s[20];
  printf("introdusca su nombre\n");
  while ((nombre = getchar()) != '\n')
   {
      s[i] = nombre;
      i++;
   }
  s[i] = '\0'; // Marco el final de cadena con un caracter nulo
  printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

El código anterior tiene un defecto. Si el usuario introduce 20 o mas caracteres antes de pulsar el salto de línea entonces vamos a escribir fuera del array. Esto es un error pero eso ya sería asunto para otra pregunta.

Answer (score 3):

logre solucionar el problema, no había inicializado el vector, lo único que hice fue en lugar de:

```
int s[20];
```

coloque:

```
int s[20]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

o bien:

```
int s[20];
while (s[19]!=0)
{
   s[j] = '\0';
   j++;
}
```

Comment: Si bien tu respuesta es válida, no es necesario inicializar el array, de hecho estás de alguna manera reproduciendo la respuesta que te ha dado Jose de una manera más costosa, en vez de configurar la última posición en `\0` lo haces con todos los caracteres.

Comment: Es más, cualquiera que vea un `int s[20]` va a entender que se busca manejar un conjunto de números. Sobretodo si lo inicializas con 0.

Comment: La última solución es incorrecta. Tienes una posibilidad entre 256, pero alguna vez sucederá que `s[19]==0` y entonces el array no se inicializará. Para incializar el array a mano considera utilizar `memset`.

Comment: `int s[20]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};` == `int s[20]={0};`, si un array se inicializa parcialmente, los elementos restantes reciben un valor 0 apropiado para su tipo.