# String me guarda basura a partir de cierta posición

Tags: c++, string, dev-c++

Muy buenas.

Tengo que realizar el siguiente ejercicio: encontrar una palabra en una frase, ambos string introducidos por el usuario. He hecho lo siguiente:

```
//i controla posiciones de cadena
//k controla posiciones de palabraCadena
//principio guardará la posicion en la que se encontraría el primer caracter
//palabra guarda la palabra del usuario
//palabraCadena va copiando palabra a palabra de la frase
//encontrado guarda 1 si la palabra ha sido encontrada y 0 si no
```

```
void buscarPalabra (char cadena[]){
    int i, k=0, principio=0;
    char palabra[20];
    char palabraCadena[50];
    int encontrado=0:
    
    printf("Introdue la palabra que deseas buscar: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(palabra,10,stdin);
    palabra[strlen(palabra)-1]='\0';
    
    pausa();
    
    printf("BUSCAR PALABRA\n");
    printf ("--------------\n");
    printf ("Cadena considerada: %s\n", cadena);
    printf ("Palabra a buscar: %s\n", palabra);
    
    i=0;
    while (i<strlen(cadena)+1){
        principio=i;
        k=0;
        while (cadena[i]!=' ' && cadena[i]!='\0'){
            palabraCadena[k]=cadena[i];
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        
        if (strcmp(palabraCadena,palabra)==0){
            encontrado=1;
            break;
        }
        
        i++;
    }
    
    if (encontrado==1){
        printf ("La palabra se ha encontrado en la posicion %i.\n", principio);
    } else {
        printf ("La palabra no ha sido encontrada.\n");
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando imprimo lo que va guardando palabraCadena, me guarda mi, coche, esche, blanco, ... Mundo, y no entiendo muy bien por qué. De esta forma, ''mi'' y ''coche'' los encuentra, pero todo lo siguiente a esto no... Como dato, uso Dev C++ como compilador.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Valores "basura" en arrays?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93932/valores-basura-en-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que veo cuando termina de leer la frase hasta el espacio, no la reinicias, lo que puedes hacer es reiniciar la palabra, quedaría de esta forma tu ciclo de lectura de palabra

```
while (i<strlen(cadena)-1){
    principio=i;
    k=0;
    while (cadena[i]!=' ' && cadena[i]!='\0'){
        palabraCadena[k]=cadena[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }
    
    if (strcmp(palabraCadena,palabra)==0){
        encontrado=1;
        break;
    }
    memset( palabraCadena, 0, 50 ); // reinicio variable para la siguiente palabra.
    i++;
}
```

lo que hace `memset` es rellenar el espacio de memoria asignado a la palabra por el caracter mandado, en este caso relleno por `\0`, lo que en teoria seria reiniciar la variable.

Referencia [memset](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memset.htm)